# Laravel: Vue component is not recognized

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I created a Vue component using laravel 5.8, but the console gives me this error.

```
<front-check-user> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
```

Before creating this component I already created 20 and never had this error.

**File app.js**

```
Vue.component('front-check-user', require('./components/frontend/CheckUserEmail').default);
```

**CheckUserEmail component**

```
<template>
<div>
    <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
</template>

 <script>
  export default {
    name: "CheckUserEmail" 
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789789/vue-js-component-not-working

Comment: Hi, I inserted already 20 components...the problem is that now every component I create is not recognized...